# JavaScript - Time Logout, click reset Time Logout

Tags: javascript

I have a code that gives the time of 20min and then disconnects the user. It's working normal. However, I need that if the user is working on the page, the team returns to the initial value, as I use a lot of ajax and the page ends up not updating as it should to return to the initial one.

**HTML**

```
<h2 id="theTime" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px; color:#FFF;">20:00 </h2>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#index-body").click(function() {
    var newTime = "s";
    sivamtime(newTime);
});
```

JavaScript - timeLogout

```
min=20;
sec=0;
var now = new Date();
var expire_time = new Date(now.getTime() + (min * 60000));
var timer_ticket = null;

function sivamtime(newTime) {
    var progressive_time = new Date();
    if((expire_time - progressive_time) < 1 || (min == 0 && sec == 0)){
        //$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $("#modal-body-info").html('<b>Por segurança</b>,<br> Tempo esgotado, não utilizou o site no prazo de 20 minutos');
        $('.logout').click(function() {
          window.location='login.php';
        });
        //});
    } else{
        min = "20";
        sec = "00";
        var countdown = (expire_time - progressive_time) / 1000;
        min = Math.ceil(countdown / 60) - 1;
        sec = Math.ceil(countdown % 60) - 1;
        if (min<=9 ) { min="0"+min; }
        if (min==0) {min="00";}
        if (sec<=9) { sec="0"+sec; }

        time = min + ":" + sec + " " ;

        if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById('theTime').innerHTML = time; }
        else if (document.layers) {
            document.layers.theTime.document.write(time);
            document.layers.theTime.document.close(); 
        }
            timer_ticket = setTimeout("sivamtime()", 1000);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        sivamtime();
});
```

Comment: do you mean if the page is idle for some time?

Comment: This is already working, when it arrives in 20 minutes the modal locks the page.
What I want is that when you click on something inside the "body" the time will restart

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple structure on jsFiddle where you can refer from:

[Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/eywjt6mo/)

HTML:

```
<div id="thebody"  style="border:1px solid">
    <br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
 let theTimer = function(callback) {
  let timerId

  this.stop = () => {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId)
  }

  this.start = () => {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId)
    timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, 2000)
  }
}

let newTimer = new theTimer(function() {
  console.log("Done!")
})

$("#thebody").click(function(){
   console.log('timer start/restart')
   newTimer.stop()
   newTimer.start()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it that way and it's not zeroing.
Although the console log is showing "Hello"

```
min=20;
sec=0;
var now = new Date();
var expireTime = new Date(now.getTime() + (min * 60000));
var timerTicket = null;

function logoutTimer(newTimer) {
    var progressiveTime = new Date();
    if((expireTime - progressiveTime) < 1 || (min == 0 && sec == 0)){
        //$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $("#modal-body-info").html('<b>Por segurança</b>,<br> Tempo esgotado, não utilizou o site no prazo de 20 minutos');
        $('.logout').click(function() {
          window.location='login.php';
        });
        //});
    } else{
        min = "20";
        sec = "00";
        var countdown = (expireTime - progressiveTime) / 1000;
        min = Math.ceil(countdown / 60) - 1;
        sec = Math.ceil(countdown % 60) - 1;
        if (min<=9 ) { min="0"+min; }
        if (min==0) { min="00"; }
        if (sec<=9) { sec="0"+sec; }

        time = min + ":" + sec + " " ;

        document.getElementById('theTimer').innerHTML = time; 

        timerTicket = setTimeout("logoutTimer()", 1000);

        if(newTimer){ clearTimeout(timerTicket); console.log("Ola"); }

    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {      

    $("#index-body").click(function(){
        var newTimer = true;
        logoutTimer(newTimer); 
    });    
    logoutTimer();
});
```